# PHP mail does not get sent, how do I debug?

Tags: php, email

I have been trying to send email for registration, invitations and so on.

On local development, emails get sent. However once on the server no mails arrive.

I installed postfix. I was trying to setup a mail server but gave up. So currently, If I type in terminal

```
peter# mail example@example.com
```

the email arrives. However, this does not send email:

```
 $res  = mail('example@example.com', 'subj', 'bodddd');
```

not only that, but echoing `$res` gives nothing. Neither `true` nor `false`.

What and how do i do to make it working?

thanx

Comment: Try looking in your maillog if anything is triggered at all. Usually located under /var/log/maillog.

Comment: `$res` should contain something, do you have `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On` ? also try to `var_dump($res);`

Comment: format should be mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters)

Comment: @Oldskool: `Oct 27 07:53:12 mail postfix/sendmail[3127]: fatal: Recipient addresses must be specified on the command line or via the -t option`. 

@user973254: good one, var_dumps to `false`; 

Still not clear what to do

Comment: @Oldskool, it might be /var/log/mail.log or /var/log/mail.err

Comment: @madhudev: header and parameters are optional: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: _Oct 27 07:53:12 mail postfix/sendmail[3127]: fatal: Recipient addresses must be specified on the command line or via the -t option_ Seems to me as if you need to configure sendmail in your php.ini correctly

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to your comment above, it looks like your sendmail path is either wrong or commented out in your php.ini. It should be something like this:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

If you're unsure where your sendmail binary resides, you may find it by using:

```
whereis sendmail
```

Comment: yes, I had to add the `-t` at the end. I don't know what it does or why it was missing, but it's working now. Graciaz

Comment: You could also use "which sendmail" instead of whereis this will only bring up the binary in the results.

Comment: Nice, the "-t -i" flags indeed made the difference for me! :) What do they do?

Comment: @LuisMiguelSerrano from  `## man sendmail` "-i     Do not strip a leading dot from lines in incoming messages, and do not treat a dot on a line by itself as the end of an incoming message.  This should be set if you are reading data from a file." ............ and "-t     Read message for recipients.  To:, Cc:, and Bcc: lines will be scanned for recipient addresses.  The Bcc: line will be deleted before transmission."

Answer (score 9):

The solution that worked for me on shared hosting was to use the `-f` additional parameter in the `mail` function. Instead of ...

`mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);`

I had to use ...

`mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, " -fvaliduser@validdomain.com");`

According to [the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) the additional parameters are provides as additional arguments to sendmail. Note that the lack of space between `-f` and the email seems intentional.

In my case on one particular host I did not have access to the postfix/sendmail logs. The original command returned true and a cpanel log showed it was accepted for delivery, however the recipient never received it.

Comment: this solved my problem sending to gmail. Thanks

Comment: this seems to depend on and might also exist in the configured 'sendmail_path'. check phpinfo() on that.